# What is the default namespace for HTML / HTML5?

Tags: xml, html, xml-namespaces

According to this [page](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/namespaces.html) by some user named "w3c" the default namespace for HTML is:

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
```

He's obviously wrong since xhtml was used for a failed XML based HTML4 standard. What is the correct namespace I should use?

Background: 
I'm writing an app that uses XML. I want to be able to save data on the XML node using namespaces. For example,

```
<s:Button width="100" height="100" html:color="blue" color="black" />
```

The XML parser needs a namespace for the "html" prefix to be valid.

Comment: *`"by some user named "w3c""`* is that a joke?

Comment: XHTML has not failed, still in heavy use, and was not based on HTML4. If you are using XML, and are planning on transforming it to HTML, you MUST use XHTML. But your first line makes me think you are not serious so this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @torazaburo HTML5 serialised as XML is indeed XML. Also, since HTML 5 is defined in terms of a namespaced DOM, namespaces apply to "normal" HTML 5 too, albeit always the same constant `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace without it needing to be stated, except in the `svg` and `math` elements.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts W3C, the WWW Consortium, are the people who define HTML in the first place.

Comment: I think the clearer answer is that HTML has no namespace because namespaces are for XML.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As documented by the W3C, who are the body behind both the XML and HTML specifications (WHATWG has a separate HTML 5 spec, but while it in some ways out of sync with the W3C spec, WHATWG does still consider it the W3C's role to bring standardise a spec as a REC), the namespace for HTML when used with an XML serialisation (which is sometimes refered to as XHTML) is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

This namespace covers all versions of HTML with such XML serialisations that have been specified so far including XHTML 1.0 and 1.1 which were in considerable use for over a decade, XHTML 2.0 which introduced several modular ideas but which was arguably of more import as an incubator for several ideas than as an implemented version, and "HTML5 serialized as XML" which is sometimes called XHTML5.

Since the other body with a horse in the race as to just how HTML 5 is specified is WHATWG, you may note that they also say that if you are serialising HTML5 as XML then you must use the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` and with the other serialisation either not use a namespace, or use that one. Per https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_namespace_declaration.3F:

> In XHTML, you are required to specify the namespace.
>
> `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
>
> In HTML, the xmlns attribute is currently allowed on any HTML element, but only if it has the value “http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml“. It doesn’t do anything at all, it is merely allowed to ease migration from XHTML1. It is not actually a namespace declaration in HTML, because HTML doesn’t yet support namespaces. See the question will there be support for namespaces in HTML.

The next FAQ is also relevant here:

> HTML is being defined in terms of the DOM and during parsing of a text/html all HTML elements will be automatically put in the HTML namespace, `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. However, unlike the XHTML serialization, there is no real namespace syntax available in the HTML serialization (see previous question). In other words, you do not need to declare the namespace in your HTML markup, as you do in XHTML. However, you are permitted to put an xmlns attribute on each HTML element as long as the namespace is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.
>
> In addition, the HTML syntax provides for a way to embed elements from MathML and SVG. Elements placed inside the container element `math` or `svg` will automatically be put in the MathML namespace or the SVG namespace, respectively, by the parser. Namespace syntax is not required, but again an xmlns attribute is allowed if its value is the right namespace.
>
> In conclusion, while HTML does not allow the XML namespace syntax, there is a way to embed MathML and SVG and the xmlns attribute can be used on any element under the given constraints, in a way that is reasonably compatible on the DOM level.

Comment: I think your answer answers this, but here is a related, although not duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407647/do-browsers-support-an-html-document-using-namespaces-see-code.

Answer (score 5):

### XHTML

The following default namespace declaration is [***required***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict) in XHTML for strictly conforming documents:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

> The root element of the document must contain an xmlns declaration for
>   the XHTML namespace [XMLNS]. The namespace for XHTML is defined to be
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

### HTML5

The same default namespace declaration is [***optional***](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Will_there_be_support_for_namespaces_in_HTML.3F) in HTML5:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

> ... you do not need to declare the namespace in your HTML markup, as you
>   do in XHTML. However, you are permitted to put an xmlns attribute on
>   each HTML element as long as the namespace is
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

Comment: OK why wasn't it updated to something like, `http://www.w3.org/2015/html`? They are clearly refer to two different semantics.

Comment: For the same reason that the MathML namespace continues to be `http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML`; the SVG namespace continues to be `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`; the XSLT namespace continues to be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`; etc:  **Continuity**.

Comment: ... which is just a euphemism for "legacy"

Comment: But, I think they're using it wrong?!? According to MDN, 'The real answer to the question is that XML content tells the user agent which dialect the tag names belong to by giving the tags explicit "namespace declarations".' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course. Each revision of HTML should be given it's own namespace. So if SVG 2.0 came out in 2010 it would be http://www.w3.org/2010/svg.

Comment: @BoltClock: *Legacy* looks back; *continuity* looks ahead.  ;-)

Comment: @1.21gigawatts:  That's a different philosophy for namespaces, one to which W3C doesn't adhere.

Comment: Experience shows that changing the namespace when you move to a new version of a specification causes far more problems than it solves, especially when the new standard is highly compatible with the old. In most cases old applications will continue to work if you leave the namespace unchanged, but if you change the namespace, then ALL old applications will fail. The conventional wisdom is that it is better to leave the namespace unchanged, but add a "version" attribute to indicate which version of the spec is in use.