# Valid locations for namespace declarations in html

Tags: xml, validation, svg, xml-namespaces

I want to centralise the `xmlns:xlink` declaration in my html documents to avoid repeating them when using svg `<use>` tags with `xref` attributes.

Instead of

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 125">
  <use class="ic-3" xlink:href="#ic" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

I will only need to write

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 125">
  <use class="ic-3" xlink:href="#ic" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

The problem is that I that I failed in finding a good source for which locations/nodes in the html tree are valid for placing these namespace declarations. I understand that `svg` nodes are suitable and this [W3 Fools article](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) also mentions the document root as valid for XML documents, which I assumed. But is any parent node a valid location for a namespace declaration? Say, can I just put it in a parent `div` or the `body` tag? Not asking for best practice, just the legality according to xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html does not support namespace declarations in markup so you can just delete them all.

Comment: that's not strictly correct is it? for instance the namespace declaration is required in xhtml, but optional (not unsupported) in html5.

Comment: strike that, ref the WHATWG FAQ it is allowed, but does not do anything (hence not supported): https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_namespace_declaration.3F
also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34407652/200987

Comment: and the XLink namespace is included in HTML5, ref W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/namespaces.html, so you are indeed correct in saying it can be removed.

Comment: I wrote html, not xhtml in my answer. Pretty much anything is allowed, that doesn't mean it will do anything.

Comment: But does that mean that namespace prefixes are also implicitly void? Meaning instead of `xlink:href` I can simpli write `href`?

Comment: Answering myself: `xlink:` is required as a prefix before `href`s in svg documents. For instance, embedding a `<a href="http://googlecom">foo</a> will not work. It's as if all the tags live in a different context in the SVG.

Comment: @oligofren xlink:href used to be required is being phased out. Firefox and Chome support raw href, Safari does not. Edge may support href but I don't think IE does.